# Keras LSTM - 'Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:' data

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am doing simple sequence prediction. My model and data look like this:

```
def generate_rnn(input_shape):
    In = Input(shape=(input_shape[1], 1))
    x = LSTM(4)(In)
    x = Flatten()(x) # I tried both with and without flatten, same results
    Out = Dense(1)(x)
    
    model = Model([In, Out])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='MSE', metrics=['mse'])
    
    return model

X = np.random.rand(100, 5)
y = np.random.rand(100, 1)
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1)

rnn = generate_rnn(X.shape)
rnn.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
```

Firtst time when I run the program, at function call `rnn.fit()` I get following error message:

> File
> "C:\Users\achib\Anaconda3\envs\deep\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py",
> line 1237, in dtype
> return x.dtype.base_dtype.name
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'

If I run `rnn.fit()` again in console, I get following error message:

> ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but
> got:',

And then my `y` variable gets printed. I have worked with LSTM networks in Keras before, but its my first time encountering such an issue? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the Model class ->https://keras.io/api/models/model/#model-class

According to this, Model class must receive input and output as different parameters and not as a part of the same list. That's what the-

> ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:',

means. The model's target variable(y) is empty. So removing the square bracket should help.

Hope this helped.

May the force be with you.

Comment: That solved it! For some reason I thought it was passed to a model as a single list

Comment: Happens all the time. The tiniest of stuff gets overlooked and boom, no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that your variables names are `In` and `Out`. These are informally "reserved" keywords if you're using `ipython`, for instance in PyCharm, Jupyter Notebooks, or Spyder.

When you run some code and see:

```
Out[2]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

`Out` is a dictionary of past outputs:

```
Out
```

```
{2: array([1, 2, 3, 4])}
```

Same thing for `In`, it's a dictionary of past inputs. So when you assign a variable to `In`, `Out`, `_`, or `__`, it might behave in weird ways, because `ipython` may change these variables.

**tl;dr** rename your variables to something else than `In` and `Out` and try again

Comment: Renaming those variables did not work. I am using Spyder IDE. But the issue does seem to be with the way I am building the model, `Sequential()` seems to work fine

Comment: oh, that's unfortunate. Spyder also uses the `ipython` console so the advice still stands